CSS to display iFrame over the top of all elements when inserted inside a Shopify app block
Here is my modal that I want to take up the entire screen when opened:
<div id="myModal" class="modal-gift">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="https://my.ngrok.app/web" class="modal-iframe"> 
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>

And then the CSS that I have now
.modal-gift {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1000; /* High index to sit above everything on the page */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1002; /* Above the overlay */
}

.modal-iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.modal-content, .modal-iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

And then this is what is happening now, where the modal is constrained inside another div for some reason.. 
Where did I go wrong?

I don't see how it can happen other than the aside being an iframe.
Do some inspect on the rendered html to see if it is.
If not check what's impeding your modal to open.
